# Burn bootloader from Arduino Nano to Atmega chip

Tags: arduino, bootloader

As seen from the above question, I need to know how to use an Arduino Nano to burn the bootloader onto an Atmega chip. The Arduino website only shows how to do it from an Arduino Uno chip configuration.

Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: Could you add the link to the Arduino bootloader tutorial?

Comment: And this is why I hate Arduino - slight differences in configuration leave users dumbfounded without step by step instructions.

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier - That's because the great majority of the Arduino docs say "do *this*", not "this is **why** you do it *this* way". You wind up with lots of procedural stuff with no explanation as to the *why*, which is the part that's essential to translating from one piece of hardware to another.

Comment: The only reason to use an Arduino to program another Arduino is "it's 10:30pm Saturday night and my programmer broke." You need a real ISP programmer. Buy a $30 Atmel programmer, or a $20 pololu/sparkfun/adafruit programmer, or at least a $10 eBay programmer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the versions of the tutorial:
http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard

This assumes the ArduinoISP sketch works on a nano. It should if its the nano also has an ATMega328 processor.

Connect the same pins by function as specified for the UNO. D10 to pin 1, D11 to pin 17, D12 to pin 18, and D13 to pin 19. These are the PDIP 28 package pin numbers. You will have to do something to the nano to deactivate reset when programming the bootloader. This is because it's wired to reset whenever anything connects to the serial port, which is great for loading in sketches, but you don't want it to reset when you go to program the bootloader. I believe the tutorial calls for putting a 10uf capacitor on the reset line of the uno. I have also seen versions calling for a resistor 110 ohms on reset to 5V. Disable reset after loading in the ArduinoISP sketch.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below link..

http://www.martyncurrey.com/?p=633

This schematic works better.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE.  Link only answers are discouraged, you should edit some of the relevant points into your answer.